# New tag proposed

Tags: discussion, tags

## Tag

I would like to propose for a new tag on the main site: [limited-audience](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limited-audience).

This tag should be used when a puzzle is not solvable by everyone, but at some degree.

## Use

### Yes

- If someone needs to know about:

  - A specific culture
  - A specific point in history or a specific historical event
  - A specific religion
  - A specific enterprise, company or organization
  - etc.
- If someone should be:

  - Working on a particular profession
  - From a particular country
  - etc.

### No

- If someone needs to know about:

  - A specific movie
  - A specific non-historical event
  - etc.
- If someone needs to be:

  - Of a different race (well, racism is not good anyway)
  - Believing to a particular religion (it's cold-hearted for some)
  - Physically different (i.e. weight, height, age, etc.)
  - etc.

Please help me to add more to this list, in the answers.

Please post one answer per person, so that I can collect different opinions about this tag.
Remember: this is tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

Comment: Also remember: On Meta, a DV means one does not agree, and UV means agree.

Comment: @Mithrandir I didn't say *anything* about that. Also, UV refers to Ultra-Violet, and DV refers to Domestic Violence. Use -1(downvote) and +1(upvote) instead.

Comment: I know. Just making sure, because some people take downvotes on meta as insults. And UV & DV are very commonly used here... o_o

Comment: *o_o* huh? How were you **suddenly surprised**?

Comment: -1 (DV) for the opinion given below.

Comment: You've got 'a specific event' under both yes and no?

Answer (score 8):

> #### I don't think this would be a good idea at all.

Reasons:

- It's a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)
- It is *complicated* and not easily understood by newcomers, and will hence be mis-used all the time. (*Your distinctions between when-to-use and when-not-to-use are not very intuitive or 'sharp'* )
- It is not possible to "do" anything with this tag. As you don't know *which* limitation is in place, there is no point in filtering all such questions out or search for them specifically. **Everybody is part of *some* limited audience, and *nobody* is part of *all* limited audience groups!**
- The same purpose is much better achieved by posting a little disclaimer at the beginning of such a puzzle. There is no need to search/filter for a tag - you only want to comunicate this extra-bit of information.

Comment: *I would like to propose for a new tag on the **main** site: [tag:limited-audience].*

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος It was understood that way. meta-tag does not refer to tags on a meta-site, but to tags which do describe a *property* of a post rather than its context. Read the article behind the link I've provided. Think about it. Let it sink in. Think about it again. It took me a while to become convinced that meta-tags are *bad*, but in the end, I became convinced. Even if I myself sometimes fall in the trap of thinking there *could* be *good* meta-tags as well....

Comment: I agree with the reasons given. It seems quite redundant since choosing many of the other tags (such as mathematics, science, computer puzzle, chess etc.) would suggest a limited audience straight away. I do also think that there'd be a lot of slippery slopes between what fits a limited audience and what does not.